# Android camera, focus slider

Tags: java, android, api, camera

I wan't to make an android camera app where the focus can be adjusted manually by moving a seekbar or entering a value into a edittext view, rather than relying on focus modes. What kind of control can I get with the standard android api and are there any third party api's for camera controls?

Comment: If my understanding is correct the Android camera APIs are quite limited

Comment: You may find this question useful: [Can I manually focus the camera on my Android phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2042/can-i-manually-focus-the-camera-on-my-android-phone)

Answer (score 1):

The camera API is here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html.  That's the only API that exists, unless you have a model of phone that exports additional functionality (and in that case it won't work on any other model of phone).